# como transformar un Stream a archivo

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

estoy consumiedno un api que me responde un stream pero esa respuesta no se como transformarla a un objeto stream para posteriormente crear el archivo, estoy usando C# net core

ej de lo que retorna el api

```
        %PDF-1.3
        3 0 obj
        <</Type /Page
        /Parent 1 0 R
        /Resources 2 0 R
        /Contents 4 0 R>>
        endobj
        4 0 obj
        <</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 3135>>
        stream
        x��Z�n����)~� �4�L7�%&a �Rr�"@AK��tH)��S�E�d�]�Yd5����CR$%�I�Um�y���?�F/��iӯ�ޓ�Z��Hů혊����*Y�k�jK�qN�<�\��3F�8\ܐ�o4�U4�lSSl�kz<[�Wɟ�i�N�i��6ٖ�X&m�y6�ؠ
        �t����ͳ��i!Z�Fg�b��4�p�ͣ?==c��bj-��%ta2SqYW����'��
        �   ��-�QO��)Z�h�b�=��湅��AH��µ�n*�!��T��3ö�s�=�Níyni�umuo!�8C�:���ʣ���4Cod�T� �9��K����g�4!/
```

tambien intente lo siguiente transformar esa respuesta en un buffer y luego crear el archivo pero se crea vacio. ej

```
MemoryStream mStrm = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DescargaDocumento["data"].ToString()));  
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(ruta + file, FileMode.Create)) 
{ 
    data.CopyTo(fileStream); 
    data.Close(); 
}
```

realizo lo siguiente DescargaDocumento["data"] porque el api devuelve un diccionario y para acceder netamente al
contenido de la respuesta realizo eso para luego transformar a un buffer

Comment: para llamar al api uso restclient

Comment: Por favor, toooodas las aclaraciones van EN la pregunta. En los comentarios no queda muy bien el código. Por favor, usa el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/465685/edit) que está justo bajo la pregunta y añade todo ahí, en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar tu `stream` pasándolo a un buffer y llamando a `File.WriteAllBytes`:

```
using (Stream stream = stringstream)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    File.WriteAllBytes("@C:\archivo.pdf", buffer);
}
```

<sub>*`stringstream` es el retorno del documento en tu api</sub>

O puedes usar `WebClient` para descargar el archivo junto a la entrada del api:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://example.com/api", "@C:\archivo.pdf");
}
```

Comment: eso tambien lo intente pero me arroja un error tratnado de castear mi respuesta a stream